# Partial differential equation about existence of limit

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Let $u(x,t)$ solves $u_{tt}-u_{xx}=0$ with initial conditions $u(x,0)=\phi(x)$ and $u_t(x,0)=0$. Here $\phi(x)$ is a smooth function that vanishes outside a bounded interval, say $[a,b]$. Show that 
>   $$
> \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \int\limits_{\Bbb R} u_x^2 dx\quad\text{ and }\quad\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \int\limits_{\Bbb R} u_t^2 dx
> $$ both exist and they are equal. Represent their values in terms of $\phi$.

I don't have a constructive idea in mind. Would appreciate if someone can direct me to specific topics or give me a general idea. Also should I involve epsilon-delta language?

Added: bounty is awarded to the answer to this problem.

Comment: How about integration by parts?

Comment: @NinadMunshi you mean on the original equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.

Using the Laplace transform

$$
s^2U(s,x)-U_{xx}(x,x)=s \phi(x)
$$

and solving for $x$ giving

$$
U(s,x)=e^{s x} \left(c_1(s)-\int^x \frac{1}{2} \phi (\eta ) e^{-\eta  s} \, d\eta \right)+e^{-s x} \left(c_2(s)+\int^x
   \frac{1}{2} \phi (\xi ) e^{s \xi } \, d\xi \right)
$$

and now use the final value theorem in

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}U_x(s,x)^2 dx,\ \ \ \int_{\mathbb{R}}s^2U(s,x)^2 dx
$$

Answer (score 2):

Use the solution to the IVP
$$
  u(x,t) = \frac{1}{2}(\phi(x+t) + \phi(x-t)).
$$
Hint: the limit is a definite integral with integrand containing $\phi'$.